# How can i put some css in a select stmt?

Tags: php, html, css

can someone help with this? I don't know how to put css in this select. Heres the code:

Gonçalo Silva

```
    if(!isset($_POST['submeterTabela']) && !isset($_POST['submeterDados'])) {

$form ="<form action=\"$self\" method=\"post\">";
$form.="Selecciona Tabela<br><br><br><br>";
    $result = $dbo->query("SHOW TABLES");
$form.= "<select name=Tabela>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
$form.= "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";
    }
$form.= "</select>";
$form.="<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submeterTabela\" value=\"Submeter\">";
    echo($form);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain further your problem ? Why do you need CSS code in this PHP code ? Maybe you should put it in a CSS file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add css by adding class to `select` element

```
$form.= "<select name='Tabela' class='REPLACE-CLASS-NAME-HERE'>";
```

And define the class in `<style>` tag:

```
<style>
.REPLACE-CLASS-NAME-HERE {
 color: red;
 /* Add class definition here, this is a comment*/
}
</style>
```

Comment: @GonçaloSilva, glad to know that my little knowledge helped somebody.